# System.Net issues

Tags: .net, system.net

When I use code like this:

```
System.Net.WebClient objClient = new WebClient();
string url = "http://google.com";
objClient.DownloadString(url);
```

It takes a couple of seconds for the connection to get established and then the downloading starts.  I reinstalled Windows yesterday and this problem started. This problem seems to happen when I reinstall Windows.

Does anybody know why this problem occurs? Thanks all.

Comment: so you are wondering why it's so slow?  is that what you're asking?

Comment: its possible...arealy i have unchecked "Enable LMHOSTS Lookup" from Connection Properties>Networking Tab>Internet Protocol(TCP/IP) > Properties>Advanced>WINS Tab>Enable LMHOSTS Lookup check box. and its takes some effect on the problem and decrease connection establish time but still not best performance it takes. i think bowth these Corrects the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you have a proxy configured in your Internet Explorer settings (Tools - Internet Options - Connections - LAN Settings). Make sure you got `Automatically detect settings` checked.

Comment: thanks man. i do this and it works perfect. more attractive is when i uncheck "Automatically detect settings" again no change where made and with last configuration so i have best performance...
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have automatic configuration of proxy enabled in your Internet Explorer? Since you don't specificially set the proxy settings of your WebClient object, it looks at Internet explorer settings.